# Which semantic is applied when its actually 'unspecified'?

Tags: swift, localization

I have a standalone custom textfield where I need to prerform some UI animations as per the text placement, but I also have localisation in my application where this textfield is being used. 
I want to know how can I check which semantic is being applied (left to right or right to left) in case of 'unspecified' because of localisation.

I could have done this by including localisation code in my textfield but I dont to. Is there any way to know the actual semantic?

Answer (score 0):

The semantic can be checked by

```
self.myView.semanticContentAttribute
```

and the direction of the actual layout by this

```
self.myView.effectiveUserInterfaceLayoutDirection
```